# Collpase partial JupyterLab Output

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab, jupyterhub

In a codeblock, I'm running a for loop in which I'm shown summary dataframe and plot for each index in list. Because of this my output become to long and difficult to read/navigate. Is there way to collapse partial output in jupyter lab.

Below I have written dummy code to illustrate the problem and objective.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython.display import HTML
for i in range(2):
    display(HTML(f'<h3> [-] Running code for {i} </h3>'))
    # Doing some calulation
    d = pd.DataFrame({'X': np.random.rand(10), 'Y': np.random.rand(10)})
    corr = d.corr()
    # Showning results in dataframe and figure
    display(corr)
    d.plot(figsize=(5, 3))
    plt.show()
```

Output of above code is shown below. In my actual code there is more than 20 heading and multiple dataframe/plot under each heading. So, I want **output to collpase when person click on heading** and shown again after person click again. Basically use heading as toggle for the output.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ipywidgets.Output`](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Output%20Widget.html) to capture each group of outputs, and display each output in an [`ipywidgets.Accordion`](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Widget%20List.html#Accordion):

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython.display import HTML
import ipywidgets as widgets

children = []
titles = []

for i in range(2):
    titles.append(f'Running code for {i}')

    out = widgets.Output()
    with out:
        # Doing some calulation
        d = pd.DataFrame({'X': np.random.rand(10), 'Y': np.random.rand(10)})
        corr = d.corr()
        # Showning results in dataframe and figure
        display(corr)
        d.plot(figsize=(5, 3))
        plt.show()

    children.append(out)
    
accordion = widgets.Accordion(children=children)
for i, title in enumerate(titles):
    accordion.set_title(i, title)

accordion
```

[image: accordion widget containing collapsible jupyterlab output]

You can even do this dynamically, iteratively updating the accordion object as you move through your workflow:

```py
#################
# cell 1 - initialize and display accordion
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython.display import HTML
import ipywidgets as widgets
import time

children = []
accordion = widgets.Accordion(children=children)
accordion

#################
# cell 2 - populate accordion as the workflow runs
for i in range(5):

    out = widgets.Output()
    with out:
        # Doing some calulation
        d = pd.DataFrame({'X': np.random.rand(10), 'Y': np.random.rand(10)})
        corr = d.corr()
        # Showning results in dataframe and figure
        display(corr)
        d.plot(figsize=(5, 3))
        plt.show()

    children.append(out)
    # accordion.children is converted to a tuple, so we must
    # re-assign it rather than appending directly
    accordion.children = children
    accordion.set_title(i, f'Running code for {i}')
    time.sleep(1)
```

[image: animation of iteratively appended accordion with ipywidget output]

Comment: Thanks for solution, it shows output as i intended. But when i restart the session (shutdown kernel, close the tab and reopen), it no longer display anything and says "Error displaying widget: model not found". Is there a way to display the output after session resetart?

Comment: I don’t think so currently. That’s a trade off with the interactive approach